# Contact Form in django

Tags: python, django, email, send, contacts

I have a contact form which all working without any error, the only thing I don't understand is when I click on send button no message receive, could anyone tell me why or what is wrong, please?
I have only one page called contact, no thanks page!
Thanks

Here is my code:
models.py
from django.db import models

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    question_  = 0
    question_one = 1
    question_two = 2
    question__three = 3

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (question_, ''),
        (question_one, 'I have a question'),
        (question_two, 'Help/Support'),
        (question__three, 'Please give me a call'),
        )

class Contact(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email   = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    subject = models.CharField(choices=Subject.STATUS_CHOICES, default=1, max_length=100)
    phone_number  = models.IntegerField()
    message = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Contact, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return 'Contact.save'
```

froms.py

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit
import floppyforms as forms

from django_enumfield import enum

class SubjectEnum(enum.Enum):
    question_  =0
    question_one = 1
    question_two = 2
    question__three = 3

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (question_, ''),
        (question_one, 'I have a question'),
        (question_two, 'Help/Support'),
        (question__three, 'Please give me a call'),
        )


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=SubjectEnum.STATUS_CHOICES, coerce=str)
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.views.generic import FormView
from .forms import ContactForm

class ContactFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = "contact/email_form.jade"
    success_url = '/email-sent/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        message = "{name} / {email} said: ".format(
            name=form.cleaned_data.get('name'),
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email'))
        message += "\n\n{0}".format(form.cleaned_data.get('message'))
        send_mail(
            subject=form.cleaned_data.get('subject').strip(),
            message=message,
            from_email="info@example.com",
            recipient_list=[settings.LIST_OF_EMAIL_RECIPIENTS],
        )
        return super(ContactFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Is the form validating?  I.e. is form_valid() being called or is it calling form_invalid() instead?

Comment: From my understanding is the valid form being called. I got this as test have create the contact models and dropdown subject. The idea of this from is to save all emails are received from the form.

Answer (score 1):

There is short and better way of doing this,

```
class Subject(models.Model):
        question_  = 0
        question_one = 1
        question_two = 2
        question__three = 3

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (question_, ''),
        (question_one, 'I have a question'),
        (question_two, 'Help/Support'),
        (question__three, 'Please give me a call'),
        )
```

---

You don't need new class, just this, where you see 0,1,2,3 is what will recognise each choice, you can put anything in the first section, e.g. 0,1,2,3, or "IHAQ" short for "I have a question"

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("0", ""),
        ("1", "I have a question"),
        ("2", "Help/Support"),
        ("3", "Please give me a call"),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with this part:

```
recipient_list=[settings.LIST_OF_EMAIL_RECIPIENTS],
```

If `settings.LIST_OF_EMAIL_RECIPIENTS` is already a list, then you are nesting it in another list.

Anyway, as a general rule, when something doesn't work, you should step through the code in your debugger or put print statements to see what is happening when the code runs. That will make the process much easier for you.

Comment: Thank you for your respond, unfortunately when I run this file alone that what I get:  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/base/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: You aren't supposed to run this file alone. Put print statements in that file, then run it by loading that page in your browser. Or, better yet, use an IDE like PyCharm or PyDev and you can use breakpoints instead of print statements.

Comment: Hi RexE, regarding the error I have is between the forms.py file and views.py file is nothing with settings or above issues. I have already ask the person who gave me the form. If anyone have an idea or any help very appreciate.

Comment: The issues is between this two file form.py and view.py.