# Do I need to do something in models.py if I'm creating a contact form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm creating a contact form in django. I've read some tuts and some of them use models.py and some of them skip the models part. What is the role of models.py in creating a contact form?

Comment: No-one can answer this without knowing what you want to do with the data submitted through your form.

Comment: I want to store the messages received through that contact form, obviously

Comment: That's not obvious at all: you might just want to email them somewhere. But if you need to store it, then, you need a model, so it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I just wanted to know the role of models.py in this whole contact form thing. I read various tuts and I was confused. So.

Comment: I don't understand what "this whole contact form thing" is. If you want to store things in the database in Django, you need a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`models.py` is *just a convention*. You are not required to put your models in any specific module, you could put everything in one file if you wanted to.

If your contact form doesn't store anything in your database, you don't need any models either. You could do everything with just a form, then email the information entered elsewhere, or write it to disk by other means.

Even if you did want to put the information into a database, you could still do that without creating a model. However, creating a model just makes this task far easier and convenient, because Django can then generate a form from that, do validation, provide helpful feedback to your users when they make a mistake, handle transactions, etc.

Comment: I want to store the messages in database and receive them in my mailbox. Should I do something like this minus the status? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071996/contact-form-in-django

Comment: I'd not put emailing in the form class, just in the view, like [Python Django e-mail form example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28400943)